# variables undefined while using pointers

Tags: c

Hello i am slowly learning c and trying my best. 
Can someone tell me why my variables are undefined?
"processId, userId, arrivalTime, priority, expectedTimeRemaining, expectedPctCPU, realTime" are all giving an error!

Please help, i provided my code. I tried reading up about structures and pointers. Followed resources, and now i am trying to implement it myself.
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

typedef enum States { NEW, READY, RUNNING, BLOCKED, SUSPENDED, EXIT, SUSPEND_READY } State;
char stateNames[7][14] = { "New", "Ready", "Running", "Blocked", "Suspended", "Exit", "SuspendReady" };


// partial - skips info needed to actually conduct process switch - contents of registers, program counter, stack pointers, ... pointers to page tables ...
// we ARE going to need some way of indicating IO needs so can decide when they should block
struct processblock {
    int processId;
    int userId;         // pointer instead?
    State processState; // Not input - initially NEW
    int arrivalTime;   // time units in simulation, not actual time
    int priority;          // base priority
    int currentPriority;   // can be upped or lowered based on what has happened with the process - not input - initially same as base priority
    int timeWaitingSoFar;   // Not input - initially zero
    int timeProcessingLastRun; // Not input - initially zero
    int timeProcessingSoFar; // Not input - initially zero
    int expectedTimeRemaining;
    struct event* waitingOn;   // ??? // Not input - initially zero
    int expectedMemoryNeed;
    int expectedPctCPU;     // to get an idea of whether CPU bound or IO bound
    bool realTime;          // whether a real-time process or not (real-time processes may need immediate attention)
    struct processblock* nextPtr; // not used in this program - but preparing for linked list version
};

//fill in the array from file
int fillArrayFromFile(struct processblock processor[], FILE*fPtr, int maxSize) {
    int count = 0;
    //unsure if realtime is a parameter, pls check and confirm with me
    while ((count < maxSize) && fscanf("fPtr,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", processId, userId, arrivalTime, priority, expectedTimeRemaining, expectedPctCPU, realTime) != EOF) {
        //fill in each part of the array
        processor[count].processId = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the processBlock object?

Comment: @MatthewKerian my professor provided that to me. i am trying to write "fillarrayfromfile"

Comment: When referring to structure members such as `processId`, you need to prefix the member name with the name of a variable of the structure, or the name of a pointer to the structure. For example, you might use `&processor->processId` or `&processor[count].processId` for the third argument to `fscanf()`.  You also need to extract the `fPtr` from the string: `fprintf(fPtr, "%d,%d…", &processor->processId, …)`.  The `&` is needed to pass a pointer to `fscanf()`; otherwise, you can use `processor[count].processId` as in the assignment — though overwriting input with a fixed value is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a linked list to store the data you need, here there is an example, this code reads the lines of a file named test.txt that has this layout:

> 100,101,20,1,50,1,0
>
> 102,105,30,1,55,1,1
>
> 101,10,40,0,56,1,1

and store all the values in a linked list, that contains your structure. I hope you'll learn something new, happy coding!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

typedef enum States { NEW, READY, RUNNING, BLOCKED, SUSPENDED, EXIT, SUSPEND_READY } State;

char * stateNames[7] = { "New", "Ready", "Running", "Blocked", "Suspended", "Exit", "SuspendReady" };


struct processblock {
    int processId;
    int userId;
    int arrivalTime;
    int priority;
    int expectedTimeRemaining;
    int expectedPctCPU;
    int realTime;          // scanf can't read boolean


    State processState;
    int currentPriority;
    int timeWaitingSoFar;
    int timeProcessingLastRun;
    int timeProcessingSoFar;
    int expectedMemoryNeed;
};

struct Node
{
  struct processblock pblock;
  struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node * List;

void NewNode(List * p , struct processblock pb) //function that creates new linked list nodes
{
    List temp;

    temp = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->pblock = pb;
    temp->next = *p;

    *p = temp;
}

int fillArrayFromFile(char *filename, List * p) {

  FILE *fPtr;
  int count = 0;
  struct processblock pb;
  char * buffer;
  buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct processblock));

  if(!(fPtr= fopen(filename, "r")))
  {
    perror("No File");
    fclose(fPtr);
    return 0;
  }

  while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct processblock),fPtr))//read every line of file and store them in a buffer
      {
        if(sscanf(buffer,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &pb.processId, &pb.userId, &pb.arrivalTime, &pb.priority, &pb.expectedTimeRemaining, &pb.expectedPctCPU, &pb.realTime) == 7 ) // read from the buffer
        {
          NewNode(p, pb); // creates new node from filled structure
          count++;
        }
      }
  free(buffer);
  fclose(fPtr);
  return count;
}

void ViewElements(List p)
{
  struct processblock pb;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
    pb = p->pblock;
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", pb.processId, pb.userId, pb.arrivalTime, pb.priority, pb.expectedTimeRemaining, pb.expectedPctCPU, pb.realTime);
    p = p->next;
  }

}
int main()
{
  List HeadNode = NULL;

  printf("Loaded %d lines\n", fillArrayFromFile("test.txt", &HeadNode));
  ViewElements(HeadNode);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! it was way more than i needed and i understand it! Thank you!